# SQL count(distinct)

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Need help with a count(distinct), I am trying to display a count of distinct (MG) items

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (50)
    O.ID,
    O.salesarboristidyominame AS Arborist,
    CASE A.accountcategorycode
        WHEN '200000' THEN 'Prospect'
        WHEN '200001' THEN 'Client'
    END AS Category,
    CASE O.proposaltype
        WHEN '1' THEN 'Standard'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Renewal'
    END AS Proposal_Type,
    O.name AS Opportunity_Number,
    O.proposaldate AS Proposal_Date,
    CASE O.statecode
        WHEN '0' THEN 'Open'
        WHEN '1' THEN 'Won'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Lost'
    END AS Status,
    O.estimatedvalue,
    O.soldtotal,
    O.unsoldtotal,
    **Count(distinct P.hierarchypath) AS MG_Count**
FROM d365prd_opportunity O
JOIN d365prd_account A
    ON O.soldtoid = A.Id
JOIN d365prd_opportunityproduct OP
    ON O.opportunityid = OP.opportunityid
JOIN d365prd_product P
    ON OP.opportunityproductid = P.productid
WHERE O.proposaldate > '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'd365prd_opportunity.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

**Update**
I'm trying to merge the COUNT into the main query. For this specific example, the main query returns 7 rows, all rows belong to 1 MG. The count query returns the value of 1 which is correct. I just need to megre that COUNT into the main query maybe as a subquery somehow?

**See screenshots below:**

[Main Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij7cY.png)
[Count Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnMyy.png)

Comment: just `group by` after `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `group by` in your query. whenever you use aggregate functions like `count, sum, avg` then you have to do `group by` of non- aggregated columns. Add following code after `where` clause.

```
group by
    O.ID,
    O.salesarboristidyominame,
    CASE A.accountcategorycode
        WHEN '200000' THEN 'Prospect'
        WHEN '200001' THEN 'Client'
    END
    CASE O.proposaltype
        WHEN '1' THEN 'Standard'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Renewal'
    END,
    O.name,
    O.proposaldate,
    CASE O.statecode
        WHEN '0' THEN 'Open'
        WHEN '1' THEN 'Won'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Lost'
    END,
    O.estimatedvalue,
    O.soldtotal,
    O.unsoldtotal
```

Comment: I added the group by from above and am returned 0 results. is the Count(distinct P.hierarchypath) AS MG_Count corrrect?

Comment: provide tables and expected output.

Comment: I added screen shots and more definition.